# how would i summon an armor stand holding out his hands facing east in 1.11

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

me and my little sister made a map making team called command-craft and we are working on our first map. but we need to know how to summon an armor-stand with its arms out like it wants a hug but I also want it to face east. I have the arms sticking out part, but I cant find out how to do the facing east part. here's my command so far.

```
/summon armor_stand ~ ~ ~ {Pose:{RightArm:[270f,0f,0f],LeftArm:[270f,0f,0f]},ShowArms:1}
```

could someone please help?

Answer (score 1):

You need the `Rotation` tag:

`/summon armor_stand ~ ~ ~ {Rotation:[*value Y*,*value X*],Pose:{RightArm:[270f,0f,0f],LeftArm:[270f,0f,0f]},ShowArms:1}`

The rotation values define the rotation on the X and Y axis (example: `Rotation:[270f,0f]`).